# WPF: can I create a template where one control always steals focus from all other elements?

Tags: wpf

I'm creating a WPF control whose template is comprised of a textbox and some other controls. No matter which control the user clicks, I want focus to be set on the textbox.

I can attach a handler to the GotFocus event of each control, but that seems not very DRY. Is there a way in WPF to automatically achieve this? Having one control inside a template which basically steals focus from all other controls inside a its parent template?

Answer (score 0):

Using the FocusManager can solve your problem. You can use style to apply it to your controls:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=alwaysMe}"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<StackPanel >
    <TextBox Name="alwaysMe" />
    <TextBox Text="Click Me!"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, first, I believe your syntax is incorrect: the correct syntax should be <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding Source=alwaysMe}"/>. At least that's the syntax that didn't give me an error. Second, it doesn't work...

Comment: The code with `Source=alwaysMe` doesn't work for me. Have you tested my suggestion separately? What error do you get?